# Example of function of bounded variation but not absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that every absolutely continuous functions are of bounded(finite) variations but converse need not be true. and the cantor function is well-known example of function of bounded variation which is not absolutely continuous. I want to know some other examples. Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/continuous-and-bounded-variation-does-not-imply-absolutely-continuous

Comment: And if you don't require continuity, just take a simple jump: $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: Other examples: $f(x)=\mu([0,x))$, where $\mu$ is a measure supported in a Lebesgue null set. The Cantor function is of this form, and in fact every BV function, up to removing an absolutely continuous part. 

Comment: When you are looking for a counterexample in analysis you should always have a look at the very beautiful "counterexamples in analysis" by Gelbaum and Olmsted (http://books.google.de/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false). It is very likely it contains what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real valued function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb {R} $ is of bounded variation iff it is the difference of two bounded monotonically increasing functions. This gives you many -- in fact all real real valued -- examples.

(See, eg., Rudins 'Real and Complex Analyis', Exercise 7.13)